# Node.js MySQL call query inside of a callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Im trying to run a query inside of the callback result of another query in Node.js.
Here is my sudo code

```
myConnect.connect(function(err) { 
        if(err) throw err;
        var res;
        myConnect.query(getDecks, function(err, result, fields){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(result.length);
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length;  i++){
                        var deckOne = result[i];
                        for(var j = i+1; j < result.length; j++){
                                var deckTwo = result[j];
                                var sim = DeckCompare(deckOne, deckTwo);
                                if(sim*100 >=  15){
                                     
                                        console.log("Comparing Deck: " + i + " and Deck: " + j);
                                        console.log(" Match: " + sim*100);
                                        var dateTwo = deckTwo[Object.keys(deckTwo)[1]];
                                        var dateOne = deckOne[Object.keys(deckOne)[1]];
                                        var ins = "INSERT INTO `deck_matched` (`DECK_ONE`, `DECK_TWO`, `DATE_ONE`, `DATE_TWO`) VALUES ('" + i + "','"$
                                        myConnect.query(ins, function(error, res){
                                                if(error) throw error;
                                        });
                                }
                        }
                }
        });
});

function DeckCompare(d1, d2){
        var match = 0;
        var tmp = 0;
        for(var i = 2; i < 54; i++){
                var c1 = d1[Object.keys(d1)[i]];
                var c2 = d2[Object.keys(d2)[i]];
                if(c1 == c2)
                        tmp++;
        }
    match = tmp/52;
        return match;
}
```

The first query and second query both work individually, but when I try to call a second query inside of the original query Node.js doesn't run the second query at all. I don't end the connection in the callback at all. I have also tried to get the result object out of the original callback but I don't know how since I'am new to javascript.

EDIT 1
Added my actual code instead of sudo code to reduce confusion.

EDIT 2
Added a callback in the second query.

EDIT 3
Here is my updated code and it still doesn't call that second query. It prints out the "Comparing Deck" but doesn't print out the "INTERNAL CON" nor does it insert. It doesn't throw any errors. I know it has something to do with query() being asynchronous because if the forloops are small ie not looping through 15000 results then it will run the second query.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var myConnect = mysql.createConnection({
        host            : "localhost",
        user            : "root",
        password        : "",
        database        : "fiftytwo_fact"
});

var getDecks = "SELECT * FROM `deck`";

myConnect.connect(function(err) { 
        if(err) throw err;
        var wait = false;
        var goodDecks = new Array();
        var goodDates = new Array();    
        myConnect.query(getDecks, function(err, result, fields){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(result.length);
                search(result); 
        });

});
function search(result){
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length;  i++){
                var deckOne = result[i];
                for(var j = i+1; j < result.length; j++){
                        var deckTwo = result[j];
                        var sim = DeckCompare(deckOne, deckTwo);
                        if(sim*100 >=  15){
                                console.log("Comparing Deck: " + i + " and Deck: " + j);
                                console.log(" Match: " + sim*100);
                                var dateTwo = deckTwo[Object.keys(deckTwo)[1]];
                                var dateOne = deckOne[Object.keys(deckOne)[1]];
                                myConnect.connect(function(err){
                                        if(err) throw err;
                                        console.log("INTERNAL CON");
                                        var ins = "INSERT INTO `deck_matched` (`DECK_ONE`, `DECK_TWO`, `DATE_ONE`, `DATE_TWO`) VALUES ('" + i  + "','" + j + "','" + dateOne + "','" + dateTwo + "')";
                                        myConnect.query(ins, function(err,result){
                                                console.log("INSERTED");
                                        });
                                });
                        }
                }
        }
}



function DeckCompare(d1, d2){
        var match = 0;
        var tmp = 0;
        for(var i = 2; i < 54; i++){
                var c1 = d1[Object.keys(d1)[i]];
                var c2 = d2[Object.keys(d2)[i]];
                if(c1 == c2)
                        tmp++;
        }
    match = tmp/52;
        return match;
}
```

Comment: first line, do you forget to add method .query ? (may be this not help)

Comment: @nuttertools sorry, its sudo code, the main thing I'm after is just trying to figure out why I can't call a .query in another .query callback. I dont get any errors node js just doesn't seem to run the second query.

Comment: Do not ignore error handling for the 2nd query. Please set the callback and handle those errors properly. At least console.log them. Then you'll get some clue on this.

Comment: @srimaln91 I do in my actual code. But node js doesnt run it at all.

Comment: The code  in the edit does not provide a callback for `connection.query(ins)`. Also I would check if the first occurrence of `connection.query(ins)`  (at the top of the `if` branch code) should be there.

Comment: @traktor sorry about that, but even with the callback and removal of the first query(ins) it still doesn't run the second query.

Comment: The `$` on the end of `var ins = .... $` is a syntax error. If no syntax error is being reported, the script being edited and the one Node is executing are different scripts.

Comment: @traktor nano adds  $ to indicate the line continues but its not displaying it all. I've ran that sql outside of the callback with no errors. As soon as its in the callback the query function just doesn't run and I get no errors